# aligning function declarations in clang-format

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I have problem with function declaration alignment.

Consider:

```
RplInstanceS* RplGetInstance(inst_t instID, uint8_t createFlag);
RplDagS* RplGetDag(RplInstanceS* inst, RplAddrS* dagID, uint8_t createFlag);
void RplFreeInstance(RplInstanceS* inst, uint8_t forced);
void ResetDioTrickle(RplDagS* dag);
RplDagS* GetNextInuseDag(int* state);
void    RplFreeAllInstances(void);
uint8_t CountAllInstances(void);
uint8_t StartAllInstances(void);
```

I was hoping there could be a clang-format option to convert it to:

```
RplInstanceS* RplGetInstance(inst_t instID, uint8_t createFlag);
RplDagS*      RplGetDag(RplInstanceS* inst, RplAddrS* dagID, uint8_t createFlag);
void          RplFreeInstance(RplInstanceS* inst, uint8_t forced);
void          ResetDioTrickle(RplDagS* dag);
RplDagS*      GetNextInuseDag(int* state);
void          RplFreeAllInstances(void);
uint8_t       CountAllInstances(void);
uint8_t       StartAllInstances(void);
```

Comment: Good question, it would be also interesting how to setup clang-format to not destroy such an alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option specific to functions but there is the `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` option which if set to `true` aligns consecutive declarations.

This can be used along with `PointerAlignment` option with value set to `PAS_Left` (in configuration: Left) which will align pointer to the left.

The combination of these two options should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry seems, the options do not work with clang-format-3.8, but with clang-format-6.0 it seems to work just fine.